# Geolocation from WIFI and/or WIFI SSID to block website access

Tags: javascript, c#, geolocation, wifi, ssid

I'm looking for a way, and wondering if it's even possible, to get either the geolocation of a mobile pc, mainly laptops, to block access to a specified website.  I'm not looking to block access to the internet or websites, just the website I'm building.

Idea: 
 Is this possible with grabbing a pc's WIFI SSID list and looking for newly added SSIDs in a specified time?

Comment: Do you have control of the laptops in question, or are you looking to block a class of clients like "everyone in China"?

Comment: it's possible - but easy to get around.

Check out this link here [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-fake-location-firefox-internet-explorer-chrome/) -- shows just how easy it is to fake a location.

Comment: Brian - I do have control of the laptops, but these are government laptops. So I do have access to the laptop's resources.

Comment: Andrew - This isn't a big worry for me. The users are not highly pc literate, and are government employees.

Comment: Each user has login credentials, and should be able to login from any pc in the office, just not a "mobile" pc. If the office buys new pc's I would like to keep the office from contacting me to add it to a not accessible list.